# How to go back to a previous page after creating or editing data in PHP, Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

How to go back to a certain previous page after submitting input data in a page. I have this "edit info" button to the two different pages. This "edit info" button will be redirected to only one "Edit info" page. What I want to execute is if I am in 1st page and going to edit an info and redirect to only one "Edit info" page, after editing I will be redirected to the previous page which is the 1st page, same goes when I want to edit an info in 2nd page. I am already using 'history.go(-1)', and '(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))' or back and it's not working.

How will I fix this, I guess it's in my parameter or the whole condition.

```
    '''
    if($user_no > 0){
        $result = $this->User_Model->update($data,$user_no);
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
            if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'index.php/home'){
                $previous_page = base_url().'index.php/home';
            }else{
                $previous_page = base_url().'index.php/faculty/detail/'.$user_no;
            }   
        }  
    }
    else{
        $result = $this->User_Model->create($data,$user_no);
        $previous_page = base_url().'index.php/faculty';
    }
    $_SESSION['result'] = ($result) ? 'SUCCESS!' : 'ERROR!';
    redirect($previous_page);
    '''
```

Comment: This code only redirect me to the second page. ''' if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
            if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'index.php/home'){
                $previous_page = base_url().'index.php/home';
            }else{
               *** $previous_page = base_url().'index.php/faculty/detail/'.$user_no;***
            }   
        } '''

Answer (score 1):

you need to define the path inside the base_url() function like this (only if the detail function in your controller contains an parameter!!):

```
$previous_page=base_url('index.php/faculty/detail/'.$user_no);
```

---

or by using `<a href>` tag inside your button like this will make it easier:

```
 <a href="<?php if(condition-1)
{ 
   echo base_url('index.php/home/')?>" 
}
else { echo base_url('index.php/faculty/detail/'.$user_no)}?>"
}>Submit</a>
```

Comment: Still the same result. I think I forgot to state my idea of using the '$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']'. I just want to redirect to one of the two previous pages after editing an info. I use '($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'index.php/home')' condition to check if this edit info page has a previous page of either a 1st page - 'index.php/home' or 2nd page - 'index.php/faculty/detail/.$user_no'.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to state my idea of using the '$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']'. I just want to redirect to one of the two previous pages after editing an info. I use '($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'index.php/home')' condition to check if this edit info page has a previous page of either a 1st page - 'index.php/home' or 2nd page - 'index.php/faculty/detail/.$user_no'.